# I'm trying to send multiple data using jquery and ajax to another page to check if a value is present in database or not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```js
function checkAvailability() {
 $("#loaderIcon").show();
 jQuery.ajax({
 url: "check_availability.php",
 data:'flatno='+$("#flatno").val(),
 type: "POST",
 success:function(data){
  $("#flatno-availability-status").html(data);
  $("#loaderIcon").hide();
 },
 error:function (){}
 });
}
```

```html
<div>
<input name="block_id" type="hidden" id="block_id" value="somevalue">
</div>
<div id="frmCheckflatno">
  <label>Flat Number:</label>
  <input name="flatno" type="text" id="flatno" onBlur="checkAvailability()"><span id="flatno-availability-status"></span>    
</div>
<p><img src="LoaderIcon.gif" id="loaderIcon" style="display:none" /></p>
```

Script sends the value `flatno` to `check_availability.php` and queries info from database. Now I need to send two values - `flatno` and `blockno` to `check_availability.php` so that I can check database using 2 constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function checkAvailability() {
    var flatnoValue = $("#flatno").val();
    var blocknoValue = $("#block_id").val(); 
 $("#loaderIcon").show();
 jQuery.ajax({
 url: "check_availability.php",
 data:'{flatno:flatnoValue,blockno:blocknoValue},
 type: "POST",
 success:function(data){
  $("#flatno-availability-status").html(data);
  $("#loaderIcon").hide();
 },
 error:function (){}
 });
}
```

```html
<div>
<input name="block_id" type="hidden" id="block_id" value="somevalue">
</div>
<div id="frmCheckflatno">
  <label>Flat Number:</label>
  <input name="flatno" type="text" id="flatno" onBlur="checkAvailability()"><span id="flatno-availability-status"></span>    
</div>
<p><img src="LoaderIcon.gif" id="loaderIcon" style="display:none" /></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Send an array to your backend:

```
<script>
    function checkAvailability() {
        $("#loaderIcon").show();
        var fn = $("#flatno").val();
        var bn = $("#blockno").val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "check_availability.php",
            data: {flatno: fn, blocno: bn},
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#flatno-availability-status").html(data);
                $("#loaderIcon").hide();
            },
            error: function () {}
        });
    }
</script>
```

Of course is better to check is there any values in both fields before calling php script.

Comment: great. mark the aswer then in order to close the topic.